Different navigationBarTitleDisplayMode behaviour between iOS 17 and iOS 18
I have this bottom sheet in my app I'm building for a tutorial (100 days of Swift UI), and I noticed that the exact same code for showing a bottom sheet with a title has different effects on iOS18 vs iOS17.
It seems like the .automatic option for .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode behaves differently across iOS versions and it's driving me crazy.
This is my ContentView:

import SwiftUI

@Observable
class Expenses {
    var items = [ExpenseItem]() {
        didSet {
            if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(items) {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "items")
            }
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        if let encoded = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "items") {
            if let decoded = try? JSONDecoder().decode([ExpenseItem].self, from: encoded) {
                items = decoded
                return
            }
        }
        items = []
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var expenses = Expenses()
    @State private var showingAddExpense = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(expenses.items) { item in
                    Text(item.name)
                }.onDelete(perform: removeItems)
            }
            .navigationTitle("iExpense")
            .toolbar {
                Button("Add expense", systemImage: "plus") {
                    showingAddExpense = true
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingAddExpense) {
                AddView(expenses: expenses)
            }
        }
    }

    func removeItems(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        expenses.items.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

and here's my AddView:
import SwiftUI

struct AddView: View {
    @State private var name = ""
    @State private var type = "Personal"
    @State private var amount = 0.0

    var expenses: Expenses

    private let types = ["Personal", "Business", "Other"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(root:  {
            Form {
                TextField("Name", text: $name)
                
                Picker("Type", selection: $type) {
                    ForEach(types, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0)
                    }
                }
                
                TextField("Amount", value: $amount, format: .currency(code: Locale.current.currency?.identifier ?? "USD"))
                    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Add Expense")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.automatic)
            .toolbar() {
                Button("Save") {
                    let item = ExpenseItem(name: name, type: type, amount: amount)
                    expenses.items.append(item)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}

#Preview {
    AddView(expenses: .init())
}

As you'll see on my screenshots, on iOS 18, the title of the AddView defaults to a large title, while on 17.4 it defaults to inline (which I'm trying to achieve in this case).
Even when manually changing the display mode to .inline, it is still has more padding than I would like to and looks significantly different from the iOS 17 version.
Has anyone experienced this or can anyone point me to a resource explaining what's changed? Or is this buggy behaviour in iOS 18?




What's surprising about this? Changing things is one of the major things that updates do. Do you have something you want to achieve?

Well, I want to achieve the exact look I have in mind for the bottom sheet, which is neither of the iOS 18 versions.
And yes, while obviously changing things is part of what updates do, I would expect updates to not cause the exact same code to look totally different.
So thanks for your unhelpful answer, just trying to learn if this is a deliberate change in iOS 18, a bug, or something else I might not be aware of.

"I would expect updates to not cause the exact same code to look totally different" - unfortunately, in the world of Apple, you cannot expect that.

Thanks Sweeper. Your answer wasn't helpful. Best wishes.

A NavigationStack is quite a complex container and it does not really surprise me to hear that there are changes in behavior or appearance between major iOS versions, especially when used in the context of a sheet. If you don't want to adopt the changes and want to maintain exactly the same appearance, it would probably be better to stick to simpler structures where you have more control over the styling. Just adding a title to a sheet is certainly not too difficult to implement yourself, see this answer for an example.

The size of the title and the gap above the Form can be resolved with two small changes:

set the navigationBarTitleDisplayMode (or toolbarTitleDisplayMode) to .inline instead of .automatic
apply .contentMargins(.top, 0, for: .automatic) to the Form to remove the gap.

// AddView

NavigationStack  {
    Form {
        // ...
    }
    .contentMargins(.top, 0, for: .automatic)
    .navigationTitle("Add Expense")
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    // .toolbarTitleDisplayMode(.inline) // works the same
    .toolbar() {
        // ...
    }
}


As mentioned in a comment, if you want more control over the styling then you might want to consider a custom header instead. See this answer for an example (it was my answer).
